# PDO exception - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions in azure

Tags: php, mysql, azure

I have my web app developed in PHP + mysql .where my application is deployed in Azure which is trying to access mysql at my machine. here the above mentioned error is displayed while connecting through azure to mysql db but it works perfectly when I try the app  locally from my system.
These are my connection strings at my .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=10.79.40.233 DB_PORT=3306 DB_DATABASE=laravel DB_USERNAME=blog 
DB_PASSWORD=root123 DB_ADAPTER=PDO_MYSQL
```

I m using php 7.1.1 version.

Comment: azure won't be able to connect to your local

Comment: using hybrid connection from the azure app I tried connecting to my system mysql db.how ll I resolve the above error

Answer (score -1):

It may be remote acces. Try to enable remote acces on your azure web panel. Also pay attention to the connection parmeters. Check if the parameters are correct (Port , Username, Password ...)

Comment: My connection Parameters are right. And enabling remote access is available at cloud service and not available at my web app panel.